# How to plot/visualize correlation values from two different methods for comparison?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, elastic-net, ggplot2

I am working on a project wherein we are comparing two methods used for modeling gene expression: one method is using elastic net and other is using lasso regression.

In one method: we see that majority of genes are showing improvement in correlation between predicted and residual expression in comparison to other method.

Method 1: 378/500 shows improvement in correlation whereas
Method 2: 122/500: gives good correlation score.

How can I plot that correlation obtained from method 1 is better than method 2? Maybe can I use boxplot or Q-Q plot?

```
My data looks like this:

dput(file[1:100,])
structure(list(geneid = c("ENSG00000196476", "ENSG00000247315", 
"ENSG00000177732", "ENSG00000125841", "ENSG00000101255", "ENSG00000125826", 
"ENSG00000125875", "ENSG00000101266", "ENSG00000125878", "ENSG00000271303", 
"ENSG00000215397", "ENSG00000101276", "ENSG00000125898", "ENSG00000101280", 
"ENSG00000101282", "ENSG00000125818", "ENSG00000125895", "ENSG00000215595", 
"ENSG00000101298", "ENSG00000125775", "ENSG00000088832", "ENSG00000088833", 
"ENSG00000196209", "ENSG00000101307", "ENSG00000089012", "ENSG00000230839", 
"ENSG00000198053", "ENSG00000101327", "ENSG00000125834", "ENSG00000226644", 
"ENSG00000125780", "ENSG00000125835", "ENSG00000088876", "ENSG00000149488", 
"ENSG00000101361", "ENSG00000101365", "ENSG00000088881", "ENSG00000088882", 
"ENSG00000132635", "ENSG00000215305", "ENSG00000132670", "ENSG00000125787", 
"ENSG00000125901", "ENSG00000101405", "ENSG00000101200", "ENSG00000185019", 
"ENSG00000215251", "ENSG00000088899", "ENSG00000198171", "ENSG00000125877", 
"ENSG00000088836", "ENSG00000277287", "ENSG00000088854", "ENSG00000088812", 
"ENSG00000125861", "ENSG00000149451", "ENSG00000088827", "ENSG00000132622", 
"ENSG00000101220", "ENSG00000101222", "ENSG00000125817", "ENSG00000101224", 
"ENSG00000275491", "ENSG00000125843", "ENSG00000088888", "ENSG00000125779", 
"ENSG00000101236", "ENSG00000088826", "ENSG00000171873", "ENSG00000171867", 
"ENSG00000101265", "ENSG00000089057", "ENSG00000277087", "ENSG00000276768", 
"ENSG00000278816", "ENSG00000277425", "ENSG00000089063", "ENSG00000132646", 
"ENSG00000101290", "ENSG00000101292", "ENSG00000226995", "ENSG00000230563", 
"ENSG00000205181", "ENSG00000125772", "ENSG00000171984", "ENSG00000089199", 
"ENSG00000089195", "ENSG00000125885", "ENSG00000275632", "ENSG00000088766", 
"ENSG00000125872", "ENSG00000278192", "ENSG00000101311", "ENSG00000125845", 
"ENSG00000125827", "ENSG00000182621", "ENSG00000101333", "ENSG00000125869", 
"ENSG00000101349", "ENSG00000243961"), rho_elasticnet = c(0.591266314719115, 
0.615209427365547, NA, 0.239901143082812, 0.760450739107573, 
NA, 0.549910642550271, 0.39395557965916, 0.634654761738937, 0.530336834857408, 
0.504964558038604, 0.397026482716831, 0.50457004777571, NA, 0.686229949596877, 
0.665462244571047, 0.490311432664584, 0.675170982435124, 0.43802636342077, 
0.57922162945216, 0.578138009971188, 0.458054206083116, 0.508575139792537, 
0.872322280376293, 0.554355290613069, 0.630080055565018, 0.56439286567471, 
0.459005729493956, 0.534494574528841, 0.536464585537367, 0.427600189370294, 
0.274811463310986, 0.543699070914181, 0.463460229513539, 0.479388301432825, 
NA, 0.44748011551166, 0.572196777860021, 0.349271639228916, NA, 
0.168268395372004, 0.48650054783066, 0.256823277742764, 0.626734548898887, 
0.627699810247947, 0.454667592677138, 0.60177775773122, 0.379363182538567, 
NA, 0.67485200229955, 0.566799355211292, 0.513682256021766, 0.599379866125332, 
NA, 0.587867560000557, 0.504315533909183, 0.566470228326088, 
NA, 0.427923604805861, 0.391216289858671, 0.373140238744086, 
0.6285866314539, 0.71646898854974, 0.422118501095895, 0.134484570266039, 
0.303413445571864, 0.609006097657911, NA, 0.573724125394775, 
0.339600725912139, 0.426185003699557, 0.37435825406584, 0.671950060575203, 
0.638194202615927, 0.646089342675266, 0.538512166227211, 0.545513608517051, 
0.293089444532146, 0.650852765226185, 0.558692593779164, 0.683706871334847, 
0.68811717740173, 0.748067306486886, 0.526122208343473, 0.715061776545806, 
0.329769820914458, 0.4106358692057, 0.579780706521083, 0.563035756571158, 
0.357935172864965, 0.65098363687083, 0.505426372064287, 0.496521991998939, 
0.525505982644064, 0.511607855183571, 0.322376765763106, 0.211382244397791, 
0.269438972486528, 0.329640960539036, 0.543569703080204), rho_lasso = c(0.566199162894552, 
0.507442010654313, 0.460561425583264, 0.427099043786296, 0.76098536028193, 
0.244518044629731, 0.465841247707502, 0.356034981129199, 0.621072400270264, 
0.594308232192673, 0.508805623009076, 0.414975203956576, 0.512526639829505, 
0.394438044817115, 0.697636193951888, 0.67556263165395, 0.507188277776163, 
0.779273167945843, NA, 0.506408881336101, 0.356263539801821, 
NA, 0.547806828153947, 0.879888844005516, 0.675758799849563, 
0.54036565206565, 0.254141174096421, 0.558373386024647, 0.539947904333412, 
0.679813625663384, 0.684144490306797, 0.405307098357913, 0.437329492582013, 
0.614529353487708, 0.310243448555879, NA, 0.403167134359088, 
0.673810087615439, 0.430944259605447, 0.341712175626587, 0.432035945711599, 
0.660414258054631, 0.350596381984159, 0.686652923068351, 0.679901380395871, 
0.502510588908273, 0.499507564087553, 0.41695573125544, 0.469841254364348, 
0.749212383041859, 0.698878689529328, 0.755472134390105, 0.709072167820479, 
0.287930028382031, 0.701794096753075, 0.53008682498047, 0.598623782925436, 
NA, 0.384564378505477, 0.563835688814849, NA, 0.354717068518319, 
0.761293130917862, 0.512227601318548, NA, 0.366543796280318, 
0.665810477636472, 0.461181388462028, 0.546353687305516, 0.444488956944372, 
NA, 0.365315923157312, 0.771723475087406, 0.701497402181332, 
0.567637007171654, 0.678532127982616, 0.593269947669895, 0.524535108857656, 
0.647505481550133, 0.568605594226885, 0.767544678302294, 0.792246518451706, 
0.79064088813361, 0.563376416884796, 0.665024863840871, 0.250738105999706, 
0.615472691563009, 0.669066689789391, 0.606432561184549, 0.354296171592173, 
0.548840014614601, 0.587754280495046, 0.421650554439162, 0.560570656886554, 
0.39151544288805, 0.296040078827479, NA, 0.35512275284544, 0.401918164265295, 
0.59871710938697)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there any way to visualize this data through a plot wherein I can show correlation obtained from elastic net is better for majority of genes in comparison to using lasso?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the correlation between the predicted value and the residuals ought to be 0, so what are you counting as "improvement"?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to compare two model: elastic net and lasso. For each gene I developed a model for gene expression and predicted expression for each gene. So we will get correlation value

Comment: The residuals should not correlate with anything.

Comment: So my residual expression is developed after regressing out the covariates from actual expression

Comment: Yes, that is what a residual is.  And it should be uncorrelated with all the variables.